# Xml serialization library for iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, serialization

Apple provides the NSArchiver and NSUnachriver for object serialization / deserialization, but this can not handle any custom xml schema. So filling an object structure with the data of any custom xml schema has to be made manually.
Since the iPhone developer community is rapidly growing, a lot of newbie programmer are despairing to deal with the available xml parsing possibilities.

The iPhone SDK only provides NSXmlParser for xml parsing, which is more useful to read certain parts of an xml file, than filling a whole object structure, which really is a pain.

The other possibility is the famous libxml library, which is written in ANSI C - not easy to use for someone who starts programming with objective-c and never learned proper C before. Event there are a lot of wrappers available, dealing with xml can be a pain for newbies.

And here my idea takes place. An XmlSerializer library which fills an object structure automatically could makes it a lot easier and increase the app quality for many programmers.
My Idea should work like this:

**The xml file**

```
<Test name="Michael" uid="28">
    <Adress street="AlphaBetaGammastrasse 1" city="Zürich" postCode="8000" />

  <Hobbies>
    <Hobby describtion="blabla"/>
    <Hobby describtion="blupblup"/>
  </Hobbies>
</Test>
```

**The classes to fill**

```
@interface Test : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    Adress *adress;
    NSArray *hobbies;
    int uid;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Adress *adress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *hobbies;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int uid;
@end

@interface Adress : NSObject {
    NSString *street;
    NSString *city;
    int postCode;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *street;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int postCode;
@end
```

**How the xml serializer should work**

```
NSError *error = nil;
XMLSerializer *serializer = [[XMLSerializer alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestFile" ofType:@"xml"]];
Test *test = [serializer deserializeWithData:data error:&error];
```

To fill the object structure needs only one line of code:

```
Test *test = [serializer deserializeWithData:data error:&error];
```

This would be so easy to use that any newbie programmer could use it. For more advanced usage the serializer could be configurable.

What do you think, would this be a helpful and popular library for iPhone and OSX Applications?

Edit:
You can see the project [here](http://code.google.com/p/orxml/), but it is fare away from release.

Comment: This will help... http://code.google.com/p/wonderxml/

Comment: Here is something similar I knocked together: http://kpmattius.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/objective-c-serialization/ If someone has time they can make it do more but it works for me :D

Answer (score 2):

The NSKeyedArchiver works precisely because it doesn't try to map onto an XML schema. Many, many XML schemas are badly designed (i.e. they're translating an in-memory object structure to an external representation format). The key problem is that the documents should be designed to make sense from a document perspective, and that that would then need to map onto whatever memory layout you wanted for your objects. Ever seen XML documents with lots of 'refid' attributes referring to other parts of the doc? Those are usually transliterated from a relational database which is just sticking angled brackets on the resultset.

So starting by assuming a one-to-one mapping between an XML document and its code representation is pretty much doomed in all but the simplest cases. Just consider where we would be today with HTML if it had been designed around the C++ objects that were used to instantiate the document in the first browser ... (well, more like Objective-C, but hey ...)

The point about NSKeyedArchiver is that you can evolve the data structure without breaking the ability to load older versions. It's unbelievably difficult to do that (properly) using some kind of automated instance-var-to-element mapping.

Comment: OP's example is a data model with simple fields that make sense to be serialized.  The question it seems to me is more about how to serialize/deserialize XML in a format other than Apple's plist format.  Likely, this is to be used to communicate data to/from a web service that doesn't run OSX (so it wasn't designed around plists).  So ideally you would write a model object with properties for each item in the schema and use it to serialize the XML result values from the service.

Comment: Furthermore the OP's example is an XML document that makes sense "from a document perspective."  In this case it's more likely that there were Objective-C objects built to support the document format in use.  Which is perfectly acceptable.  They are looking for a simple way to translate the document into an in-memory representation without writing custom parsing code for each object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite good idea, implementation wise I would do it by implementing NSXMLArchiver and NSXMLUnarchiver as subclasses of NSCoder. This way any class conforming to the NSCoding protocol could easily be serialized to and from XML.

One performance hit when serializing to XML will be the primitive values as attributes, because you can not guarantee the order an object will request data to be encoded. So if attributes is what you want, then it will be quite huge in memory buffers. But it would be a fun exercise.

As for how popular it would be? Not so popular I think. The use-case just is too small.

- Device-to-device - Simply using NSKeyedArchiver is way easier, and MUCH more compact.
- Device-to-new server - The new server would have to implement the same scheme as well, serializing to Java, C# or whatever.
- Device-to-existing server - The XML format is already fixed, and most probably not close to this.

Answer (score 1):

I have started a similar open source project. I have named it SAMIXOS. you can visit this page and try it.
Its in initial development. It works similar to what Enyra has asked.

Soon i will provide a sample code.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/samixos/

Sami

Comment: hi sami . . i am having issues in adding your library to my project . do you have a sample project which does that ??

Answer (score 1):

I have opened a related open source project, [XML stream writer for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/xswi/):

- Written in Objective-C, a single .h. and .m file
- One @protocol for namespace support and one for without

Example:

```
// allocate serializer
XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

// start writing XML elements
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Root"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];

// get the resulting XML string
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

This produces the following XML string:

```
<Root>Text content for root element</Root>
```

In my experience, cost-effective tools for mapping objects from one model (objects in memory) to another model (some XML Schema) do not exist, since the logic still has to be expressed somehow. You are better off doing the work using tools (code!?) you are familiar with.

But if you insist on using such a tool, then the way to go is to make your object model the same as the XML model.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is buried inside of the [ObjectiveResource](http://github.com/yfactorial/objectiveresource/tree/1.1) [implementations](http://github.com/lgalabru/objectiveresource/blob/cb12c9772314088c26e66c921ae17754f9d9b89b/src/Classes/NSObject+ObjectiveResource.m), and it supports both JSON and XML.  It should be pretty easy to fork that and slim it down to just the parsing by throwing out all the connection management.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with requirements in this domain and think it would be a great idea.  I've had to bully my dot net services to return JSON for easy consumption on an iPhone. A decent serialization library would be superb.