# How to generate Objective C class files from XML schema?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an XML schema that defines my data model. I would now like to have Objective C source files generated from the XML schema. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Stack Overflow question on [XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944509/xml-serialization-library-for-iphone-apps), which mentions a project along these lines.

Comment: I think that is more geared to creating instances of objects rather than creating the classes in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but it might be easier to extend than to code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details my immediate thought would be to probably use xslt for this. e.g. if you had something like (I appreciate

```
<element name="SomeEntity">
  <attribute name="someAttr" type="integer" />
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="someOtherAttr" type="string" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</entity>
```

Create a bunch of templates to translate this,e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="element">
  <xsl:apply-template select="." mode="header"/>
  <xsl:apply-template select="." mode="impl"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element" mode="header">
class <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> {
 public:
  <xsl:apply-template select="attribute" mode="header"/>

  <xsl:apply-template select="complexType/element" mode="header"/>
</xsl:template>

...
```

Though if the logic on the generation is more complex I would probably go down the road of importing the xml into an object model and programmatically process that, possibly using a template engine such as Velocity, as while it is possible complex logic in xslt is a pain.