# Write XML Documents on Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have a project where I need to convert some database entities (UML Models) to an external file (XMI, like an XML File).

Looking for XML parser or writer for Objective-c, I have only found a `NSXMLParser` on Apple's developer portal. Can I convert custom objects or `NSDictionary` to a XML (`NSString`/`NSData`) with some developed library (if someone knows one)? This can influence on app submission?

I know thats a simple object to manage the xml content and can give me some performance problems.. for me thats the motive to dont have a native library.

Comment: [your question has already been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837965/converting-nsdictionary-to-xml) [and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956509/converting-nsdictionary-to-xml); although I suspect you might also be able to do what you want to do with libxml or libxml2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy. 
You just need to know what your XML schema needs to be. Your data model will determine how your logic works. 
If any old XML is ok, look at what results you get with the convenience methods provided by NSArray and NSDictionary. 
They can writeToURL or writeToFile as property lists which are an XML format. 
You can also look at the Property List serialization docs if you need greater control.

Beyond that, it's pretty easy to write your own templating code with NSString using stringWithFormat to piece it together then write the whole thing to a file with the desired name via NSString APIs.

A custom templating solution would end up being the most flexible solution with a few string constants for the XML header and a series of for-in loops to traverse and template the data.